# Not able to enable/disable network interface for VM through Powershell run command from Azure portal

Tags: azure, powershell, networking, interface, portal

We have a requirement to disable/enable the network interface of the azure VM.
Not able to do it from the Run command

[image]

Tried this command from the internet but it is always showing a running script

" netsh interface set interface 'INTERFACE NAME' disable"

Is there any way we can enable/disable the network interface through the portal or powershell?

I know the other way that network reset in which new ip within the same network needs to be assigned but here the requirement is only to disable and then enable the network interface only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we cannot disable/enable the network interface of the azure VM from the Run command.

**RunPowerShellScript** command is used to run custom script on Azure VM not to enable/disable the network interface of azure VM and only the listed command parameters can be used while running the script.

You can detach/attach(disable/enable) the Azure VM Network Interface when the VM is in stopped state by going to the `Networking`-->`Attach/Detach Network Interface` as shown in below Screenshot from the Azure portal:

[image]